# NSPredicate not working on Swift (CoreData)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity with 1 attribute (Int) and a relation with another entity. I've created an object with an attribute and a relation and added it to the database. If I fetch all the objects in the entity I can see this one has been created, but I can't using NSPredicate with the correspondent attribute and relation.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(int_attribute == %@) AND (relation_entity like %@)", int_value, relation_object)
let list = (try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)) ?? []
```

After doing this, list is empty. And the same happens if I use NSPredicate with just int_attribute.
Context is a reference to a class DataController from ObservableObject where I have a NSPersistentContainer and init() function with loadPersistentStores.

Comment: `relation_entity like %@` => `relation_entity == %@` instead? But are the objects inside the same context?

Comment: @Larme I tried == to and it doen't work. I think objects are in the same context, since I see the object I'm trying to fetch if I get the full list on the entity (not using NSPredicate). Also, I get an empty list if I just use NSPredicate with the Int attribute. Now in every function where I use the database I do `let dataController = DataController()` `context = dataController.container.viewContext`. Would that be creating different contexts? (in DataController I have an init function with container.loadPersistentStores).

Comment: If you always uses viewContext, that should be fine. Do the fetch request without the `relation_entity` part, get the object, check `if objectFetched.relation_entity == relationObject`, and print both: `objectFetched.relation_entity` & `relationObject`, see if there are differences.

Comment: @Larme They are equal

Comment: @Larme If I type the attribute value manually, I do get the correct result. For example: `format: "int_attribute == 0"` instead of == %@. Can it be somthing wrong with saying %@ and then the value the way I'm doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In predicates, `%@` expects an object. It's not a general "replace this" indicator, and there are different specifiers for different data types. If you're matching primitive types you need something else. For integers, try `%d`. For other things, look up [`printf`-style format specifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).

Comment: thanks, that was the issue